# Не передаются параметры в метод POST

Tags: html, python, django

Нужна помощь:
В Django при обработке следующего когда views.py:

```
class PasClone(View):
    def put(self, request, treeFrom, treeTo):
        return JsonResponse({ 'treeFrom':treeFrom }, 'treeTo':treeTo)
```

в браузер возвращаются значения:

> {"treeFrom": null, "treeTo": null}

При том, что в Header-е запроса

> treeFrom=75&treeTo=75

Если

> def put
>   заменить на 
>   def get
>   то значения приходят на сервер и возвращаются в браузер. Но нужен именно метод put В чем я ошибся?

Вот содержание urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^pas_clone(/|)((?P<treeFrom>[0-9]+)|)(/|)((?P<treeTo>[0-9]+)|)$', PasClone.as_view())
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Через `HTML` формы Вы не сможете передать `PUT` запрос.

По спецификации они поддерживают только `GET` и `POST` запросы.

Для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, Вам потребуется использовать JavaScript и явно указать, что Вы отправляете данные `PUT` методом (например, с помощью `jQuery`).

***Пример:***

```js
$.ajax({
   url: '/api',
   type: 'PUT',
   success: function(response) {
     //...
   }
});
```

Некоторые предлагают туннелировать через `POST`, то есть посылать `POST` запрос со скрытым полем, в котором указывать значение `put`, но я не советую это использовать.